# perl: Can't call method "push" without a package or object reference?

Tags: perl, linked-list

I was given the assignment to implement a linked list in perl without using the built-in push,pop,shift and unshift. This is my first time learning perl, coming from c++ and java, this is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub node {
    my (@value) = @_;
    sub get {
        $next;
    }
    sub push {
        #my $next = \@_;
        if(defined($next))
        {
            $next->push(@_);
        }
        else
        {
            my $next = \@_;
        }
    }
    sub size {
        if(defined($next))
        {
            $next->size($_[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            $_[0]+1;
        }
    }
    sub myprint {
        print "$_[0]: ";
        foreach (@value) {
            print "$_, ";
        }
        print "\n";
        if(defined($next)) {
            $next->print($_[0]+1);
        }
    }
}
while(!defined($done))
{
    print "what do you want to do?\n";
    print "1 -- push\n";
    print "2 -- print nodes\n";
    print "3 -- pop\n";
    print "4 -- quit\n";
    my $val = <STDIN>;
    if ($val == 1) 
    {
        print "Type something: ";
        $input = <STDIN>;
        if(defined($top))
        {
            $top->push(node($input));
        }
        else 
        {
            $top = node($input);
        }
    }
    elsif ($val == 2)
    {
        if(defined($top))
        {
            $top->myprint(1);
        }
    }
    elsif ($val == 3)
    {
        if(defined($top))
        {
            if(defined($top->next))
            {
                $top=$top->next;
            }
        }
    }
    elsif ($val == 4)
    {
        $done=true;
    }
    else
    {
        print "Invalid option\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
what do you want to do?
1 --    push
2 --    print nodes
3 --    pop
4 --    quit
1
Type something: q
what do you want to do?
1 --    push
2 --    print nodes
3 --    pop
4 --    quit
1
Type something: w
Can't call method "push" without a package or object reference at ./linkedlistattempt1.pl line 76, <STDIN> line 4.
```

I'm guessing the "->" operator can only be used with a module or package.

I haven't gotten around to testing the other methods, I'm still working on push. I feel like the best way of doing this is to simply have a holder sub like `sub holder { $value = \@_; } but I don't understand how I would (could?) add more variables, like the next node, hence the sub within a sub design. So without the help of perl's built in functions, how would I do this?

Its important to mention I'm interested in methods that can run on the older versions, going down to 5.10. Most if not all of the tutorials are showing stuff for 5.16 or 5.18

Comment: Might not help find a relevant error, but always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Might not be relevant, but don't do `\@_`. `@_` contains aliases, so you're getting a reference to an array of elements that will change behind your back. Use `[ @_ ]`, or copy `@_` into a named array and take a reference to that.

Comment: The built-in array operators aren't very useful for a linked list anyway. You seem to have become confused between object-oriented ideas and a simple procedural design - which are you intending to use? There is little point in declaring nested subroutines - it probably doesn't do what you think it does. And you are using a variable `$next` everywhere which us never declared. `use strict` and `use warnings at the top of your program will pick up things like this for you.

Comment: I wanted a pure Object-oriented before moving on to a perl-style solution (I assume thats what you mean by procedural)?. Sorry for such a late reply. I read nested sub routines is the same as simply declaring them side by side so I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical Perl implementation using classic Perl OO would look something like this. Read the man pages [`perlootut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) and [`perlobj`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) to learn how it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package LinkedList::Node;

# Constructor.
sub new {
    my ($class, $item) = @_;

    my $self = { item => $item };

    return bless($self, $class);
}

# Read-only accessor.
sub item {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->{item};
}

# Read-write accessor.
sub next {
    my $self = shift;

    my $next = $self->{next};
    if (@_ > 0) {
        $self->{next} = shift;
    }

    return $next;
}

package LinkedList;

# Constructor. Creates an empty linked list.
sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    return bless({}, $class);
}

# Read-only accessor.
sub head {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->{head};
}

# Insert an item at the beginning.
sub push {
    my ($self, $item) = @_;

    my $node = LinkedList::Node->new($item);
    my $head = $self->{head};

    if ($head) {
        $node->next($head);
    }

    $self->{head} = $node;
}

package main;

my $list = LinkedList->new;

$list->push(2);
$list->push(5);
$list->push(9);

for (my $node = $list->head; $node; $node = $node->next) {
    print($node->item, "\n");
}
```

Comment: I did see those tutorials, I was hoping to avoid using packages (that I personally didn't write) and the push,pop shift,unshift. Perhaps this is difficult/impossible in perl and I misunderstood the assignment. Either way I like what you have here.

Comment: The code I posted doesn't use external packages and it doesn't use the core push/pop functions. It only defines a *push* method on its own *LinkedList* package. It's basically as barebone as it gets.

Comment: ah. My noob eyes couldn't tell the difference. Thanks for clearing that up